# Query individual field using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

Here in below code i am trying to log a single fetched document but entire document content is logged..what could be the possible solution..

```
  var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  var collection = db.collection('DATA');
  collection.find({'borough':'Bronx'}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  assert.equal(err, null);
  console.log("Found the following records");
  console.log(docs);
  callback(docs);
 });      
}

output :
     [ { _id: 57a47c4a0d0c207a3e0efcc9,
         address: 
                { building: '1007',
                  coord: [Object],
                  street: 'Morris Park Ave',
                  zipcode: '10462' },
         borough: 'Bronx',
         cuisine: 'Bakery',
         grades: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
         name: 'Morris Park Bake Shop',
         restaurant_id: '30075445' } 
    ]
```

Comment: use project to get individual field output. Since you are querying by 'borough' field, it returns the record which matches the query. If you want get specific field only, then project that

Comment: You want to retrieve only specific field ?

Comment: i want to fetch only borough field

Comment: You are querying with borough field and want to project too?

Comment: Anyhow, to get that collection.find({'borough':'Bronx'},{borough:1}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  assert.equal(err, null);
  console.log("Found the following records");
  console.log(docs);
  callback(docs);
 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To project specific field while using find query use the following syntax

```
collection.find({'borough':'Bronx'}, {borough:1}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  assert.equal(err, null);
  console.log("Found the following records");
  console.log(docs); // will be array with only borough field and _id
  callback(docs);
 });
```